# Will differentiable functions always have a point that is tangent to a straight line?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

If $f(x,y)$ is a differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and we are given a line $ax + by = c$, can we necessarily find a point $\left(x^{*} , \frac{c - ax^{*}}{b} \right)$ on some curve $f(x,y) = r$ (where $r$ is a constant) such that $\frac{\partial U(x^{*} , \frac{c - ax^{*}}{b})}{\partial x} = \frac{a}{b}$?

Note that the straight line has (anti-clockwise) angle between $90^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ (both inclusive) and each point on the curve $f = \text{constant}$ has slope with (anti-clockwise) angle between $90^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ (both inclusive).

I am solving a problem in which I require this. I am trying to find out if we can always find such a point. If not, under which conditions we can. By drawing graphs, I feel this is true when $f$ is strictly convex, but I can not prove that either.